# In Xcode, is there a way to sort the dropdown list for methods

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, there is a preferences option to sort the Editor Function pop-up alphabetically which is great. However, this does not take into consideration the #pragma mark headings which also appear in this list. It would be great to have this list sorted alphabetically first by #pragma heading, then by method. Is this possible? Perhaps with a script?

Answer (score 15):

I can help you a little bit:

Just hold Cmd while you click on the methods-list-item in Jump Bar. Now they are all sorted alphabetically.

Only Pragma marks are grouped together at the end of the list. That's ugly. The rest is fine.

If you want to go further you're able to click on the list-item and then start typing any search for a method name and you instantly get the search results for the appropriate methods.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the method list at the top of an editor window: not in XCode 4 - scripting is broke so there is no way to applescript it either. The list appears in order of the methods in your source file. File a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) asking for this as a feature, in theory it shouldn't be difficult for Apple to implement since the index of methods is already built.